# Disable auto download of iframe content on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, reactjs, safari

I have a modal that displays a PDF with two option, one to print and one to download.

The download option is using a blob with content-type: application/octet-stream.
The print option is using a blob with content-type: application/pdf.

The download button works perfectly, but when I open the modal in Safari on iOS, the prompt to download is automatically showing and the file is downloaded automatically. It is working on desktop devices and in chrome.

```
      const downloadBlob = new Blob([int8Array], { type: 'data:application/octet-stream;' });
      const printBlob = new Blob([int8Array], { type: 'application/pdf;' });
      const downloadFileURL = URL.createObjectURL(downloadBlob);
      const printFileURL = URL.createObjectURL(printBlob);
```

When I remove the `src` attribute from the `iframe`, the auto download prompt doesn't show. Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
      {fileType === 'application/pdf' ? (
        <>
          <div id="wrapperDiv" ref={wrapperRef}></div>
          <iframe id="documentObject" src={`${fileSrc}#view=fitH`} title={fileName} style={{ display: 'none' }}>
            This browser does not support this document type. Please download the document to view it:
          </iframe>
        </>
```

Print button:

```
const element: Window = window.frames;
      element[0].focus();
      element[0].print();
```

Comment: is there a way to delay the download? When it originally pops up on iOS, it says "Do you want to download "Unknown"? This happens without even clicking the print or download button

Answer (score 0):

For printing use:

```
printPDF(pdfUrl) 
{
    var w = window.open(pdfUrl);
    w.print();
}
```

For downloading:

```
downloadPDF(pdfUrl) 
{
    var anchor = document.createElement('a');
    anchor.href = pdfUrl;
    anchor.target = '_blank';
    anchor.download = "filename.pdf";
    anchor.click();
}
```

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download

If the download attribute is not supported, it should fallback to just opening the PDF in a new tab.